# Angular subscribe method executed at the very end

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't understand the order in which my code is executed. Here I provide 2 functions and output that is received:

`component:`

```
onSubmit(model) {
    this.submitted = true;
    let newUser: User;
    newUser = this.usersService.addUser(this.model);
    this.notifyParentOnAdd.emit(newUser);
    console.log('saved Model as json ' + JSON.stringify(newUser));

  }
```

`service:`

```
 addUser(user: User)  {
    let savedModel: User = new User('','','',['']);
    this.httpClient.post<User>('http://localhost:8080/user/create', user).
      subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res.id);
        console.log(res.firstName);
        console.log(res.lastName);
        console.log(res.groups);
        savedModel.id = res.id;
        savedModel.firstName = res.firstName;
        savedModel.lastName = res.lastName;
        savedModel.groups = res.groups;
      });
      console.log('user-service: ' + savedModel);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(savedModel));
      return savedModel;
  }
```

And the output is as follows:

```
users.service.ts:35 user-service: [object Object]
users.service.ts:36 {"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"","groups":[""]}
user-form.component.ts:33 saved Model as json {"firstName":"","lastName":"","email":"","groups":[""]}
users.service.ts:26 7
users.service.ts:27 test
users.service.ts:28 test
users.service.ts:29 ["WORKERS"]
```

It clearly shows that `subscribe()` method is executed at the very end that's why `User` object is blank.

1. How to explain this behaviour?
2. How to force `subscribe()` to execute when service method `addUser()` is invoked?

Comment: No. subscribe() is not executed at the very end. What is executed much later is **the callback function** passed to subscribe(). Because HTTP is **asynchronous**. If it was not, http.post would simply return the response, instead of forcing you to subscribe and pass a callback function. Just like `putBreadInToaster(); whenToasterTellsMeItIsReady(toast => eatToast(toast)); readTweetsInTheMeanTime();`

Comment: Do NOT subscribe() in the service. Simply **return$$ the observable from the service: it represents an asynchronous, future result. Call subscribe() in the component.

Comment: Ok i moved `subscribe()` to component but that still doesn't solve my problem. How can I be sure that I received `User` object before I start to process it further?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the result of your service, you could apply other operators to you original Observable, perhaps make another http request or whatever.

Comment: Well, put the code that needs the User **inside** the callback function that is called when the user comes back from the server. `service.addUser().subscribe(createdUser => { doSomethingWithCreatedUserHere(createdUser) })`